# Why are certain menus unreadable when using a new GTK+ theme with Nautilus?

Tags: gtk, crunchbang

I installed a new GTK theme for both GTK 2.0 and 3.0, and now there are certain windows that have unreadable text in Nautilus. The text color is black on a light background, I made sure of this with the color manager in Gnome Tweak. For example, I can't see anything in the file properties dialog, or in the popups that occur when doing file operations, etc. If I highlight the invisible text it shows up. This also happens in Gnome Mplayer, I can't see any text when trying to change my preferences, so I know it isn't an issue with Nautilus.  I can see my files and the text in the pane of nautilus just fine. If I switch to one of the themes that was installed by default, everything works fine.

I'm using Crunchbang with the Fleche GTK+ theme https://github.com/hdni/Fleche

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue "Enhancement" (not maked as bug):
[github: Fleche: issue:2  **No GTK 2 theme**](https://github.com/hdni/Fleche/issues/2)
so the Fleche theme does not (fully) implement a GTK 2 theme.
Sounds like there may be some partial/stub implementation, which could mess up something if it's installed as GTK 2 theme like this.